# jmeter not showing xml response in response tab

Tags: xmlhttprequest, jmeter

Hi all please help me out with this issue. while I send following http request `("http://xyz/Scribe/Scribe.xsd")`; it does not showing any data in response tab in View Result Tree. So please help me out with that.

Thanks.

Comment: Any news on that was my answer helpful ? if yes you should accept it so that it helps other

Answer (score 0):

It's because your server does not return :
Content-Type header

As JMeter uses it to render the response and does not find it, it does not render it.

See:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54226

Issue has now been fixed, you can use nightly build:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html